# Select.. Into MS Access to SQL Server equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

Lets for arguments sake say I have the following **query** in **MS Access**

```
select  id, value into newtable
from oldtable
```

I  need to replicate that in **sql server** stored procedure
Would it be as follows:

```
Delete newtable if exists  
Create newtable  
Copy values
```

or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: `SELECT * INTO...` is compliant syntax in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If the table doesn't exist, you would do:

```
select id, value
into newtable
from oldtable;
```

If the table does exist:

```
drop table newtable;

select id, value
into newtable
from oldtable;
```

Comment: Is the steps that you shown the exact steps to replicate the select..into behaviour? I'm not too concerned about the syntax (thanks for it though)

Comment: @Eminem . . . The syntax for `select into` is the same in both databases.  Your code doesn't need to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you already migrated the old table to the SQL server, use the following script in your procedure.

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
             AND  TABLE_NAME = 'NewTable')
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE NewTable
    END

    SELECT ID,VALUE INTO NewTable FROM OldTable.
```

The EXISTS clause will check and remove the NewTable if it is already exists in your database. There are different ways of writing the table existancy check in SQL server and you can follow any of these.

```
   IF OBJECT_ID (N'NewTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE NewTable
```

OR

```
   IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.Objects WHERE  Object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.NewTable') AND Type = N'U')
   BEGIN
      DROP TABLE NewTable
   END
```